# Web.config Remove ConnectionStrings node from Web.Release.Config

Tags: visual-studio, xslt, web-config

I have this in my Web.config so that my service will run locally:

```
  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=IPADD;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UN;Password=PW" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I need this here because the Web.Debug.Config doesn't work. So when I publish I want to remove this string because it is actually inherited from a parent Web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="DefaultConnection"/>

  </connectionStrings>
```

This doesn't seem to work... (it throws a `The entry 'DefaultConnection' has already been added.` error)

How can I remove it? XSLT?

P.s. I can't use `clear/` because it removes the Machine.Config DB Connection string to the Membership provider also throwing a different error

Answer (score 6):

Put below code:

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="LocalizationDB" 
        xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

But be careful when you do publish from visual studio. When you look on Output view. It should write you something like:

```
Transformed Web.config using Web.Release.config into obj\Debug\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
```

But if you have active "Debug" you will have `Web.Debug.config` instead of `Web.Release.config`